# Plotting 1/x not correct in pgfplots?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

When I'm drawing f(x)=1/x or similar functions, pgfplots draws asymptotes. Do I have to draw the function in two pieces with different domains, or am I missing something?

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%
    [
        grid=major,  
        x=5mm,
        y=5mm,
        xtick={-10,-9,...,10},   
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        xlabel={\tiny $x$},
        axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
        tick label style={font=\tiny},
        ymin=-10,
        ymax=10,
        ylabel={\scriptsize $f(x)$},
        axis y line=middle,
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        domain=-10:10,
    ]
    \addplot[thick] (x,{1/x});
    \addplot[dashed] (x,{1/(x-2)});
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems to be a duplicate. But using `restrict y to domain=-20:20` does not seem to help with 1/x, with 3 * x / (1 + x) it works like a charm. Weird.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. My native language isn't English...
I was looking in the answers on similar questions, but none of the answers related to the questions that I had found was solving my problem. Next time I will look even longer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to play a little with `restrict y to domain` and with the `samples` of the two plots. I don't know why but if the samples number is too low the asymptote is visible also with the `restrict y to domain`. If `restrict y to domain` is too low you have to increase a lot the sample number in order to have the graph extended until the edges of your plot.

But it is easier to play with these two values than to explain them whit words, so enjoy!

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetkzobj{all}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%
    [
        grid=major,  
        x=5mm,
        y=5mm,
        xtick={-10,-9,...,10},   
        xmin=-10,
        xmax=10,
        xlabel={\tiny $x$},
        axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
        tick label style={font=\tiny},
        ymin=-10,
        ymax=10,
        ylabel={\scriptsize $f(x)$},
        axis y line=middle,
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        domain=-10:10,
        restrict y to domain=-20:20
    ]
    \addplot[thick,samples=400] (x,{1/x});
    \addplot[dashed, samples=400] (x,{1/(x-2)});
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: strange, but it works, thanks